# How to call is_authenticated in Flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using flask-login with the following User class. At first I didn't override the `is_authenticated()` method but I thought it might fix my problem (it didn't).

I ran my code on 3 different computers. On one of them I have to call the `is_authenticated()` method as a regular method (with the `()`) and on the other 2 I have to use is_authenticated as a boolean (without the `()`).

In all the computers the interpreter is set to python2.7.
What am I missing?

```
class User(UserMixin):
    """
    Defines each user.
    """
    def __init__(self, user, pwd):
        self.username = user
        self.password = pwd

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

Here's I call the method:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = flask.ext.login.current_user
    g.username = g.user.get_id()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@flask.ext.login.login_required
def index():
    if g.user is None or not g.user.is_authenticated(): // or g.user.is_authenticated
        return redirect('login')
    return render_template('main.html', user=g.username)
```

Comment: How are you checking `is_authenticated` ?
You should do like `from flask.ext.login import current_user` and then `if current_user.is_authenticated():` for checking whether the current user who has requested it is authenticated

Comment: That's what I'm doing but like I said sometimes I need to call like that "if current_user.is_authenticated()" and sometimes like a boolean "if current_user.is_authenticated"

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling the same?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I guess you are better off with `current_user` and `current_user.is_authenticated()` g.user is used to make the a variable global so it can be accessed in any scope where current_user is a object which tells us current active user, we use g.user to make the current_user object global so it can be used anywhere

Comment: I know that's why I use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? Check if it's a boolean, or it's a function:

```
if type(is_authenticated) == type(True): # if it's a boolean, this is True.
    # Your code

else: # if not, it's a function.
    is_authenticated()
    # Your code
```

And create a function here is a good idea like this:

```
def function_name():
    if type(is_authenticated) == type(True):
        return is_authenticated
    else:
        return is_authenticated()
```

Comment: That's a good workaround actually. I'm still wondering why it works differently on different systems.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you need update `flask-login`?

Comment: That's it. I just checked the versions and it's not the same. The best way to prevent unwanted behavior is to check what type it is as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @onTheDev Kevin's solution is good, but I would still suggest you to consider the version's are same and try to solve this issue with a correct attempt :)

Comment: @NagarajTantri That's what I want to say, however always use the newest version software can prevent some errors. Usually, these errors are hard to debug :)

Comment: I did upgrade the flask-login version. That being said this application will not run on only one system but several. I just prefer to be safe.